# exploding a timestamp and adding : every 2 places

Tags: php

I have a PHP Script that has an INT in the format MMSSMS - Minutes Seconds Milliseconds defined as $time. I just need a : every 2 places in $time. Any help is appreciated.

Example: $message = 'I clocked in (MM:SS:MS) '.$time.';

the issue is the $time displays as 000044 instead 00:00:44 on echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code replaces 2 consecutive digits not on the end of the string with the digits followed by colon

```
$message = 'I clocked in (MM:SS:MS) '.preg_replace('/\d{2}(?!$)/','$0:',$time);
```

php.net/preg_replace

demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de0ce1e4466ff747f1bba2ac92331623a1b234ed

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $time = '123456';
 $str =  strval($v);
 $time = $str[0].$str[1].":".$str[2].$str[3].":".$str[4].$str[5];
 echo $time;
?>
```

Comment: Good answer, but this question seems a little confusing because an int value of `000044` evaluates to `36`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**chunk_split()**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) in conjunction with [**rtrim()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$time = '000044';

$time = rtrim(chunk_split($time, 2, ':'), ':');
```

---

**Edit**

If `$time` is an INT, you would need to convert using `(string)$time` or `strval($time)`. However, in your example you are using `000044`, so I am assuming `$time` is already a string...

Comment: Edit to remove the last `:` :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Ya just saw that. Will update, thanks :)

Comment: i think the OP said its a INT, maybe first you would like to convert it into string using strval()

Comment: @HarendraSingh Ya, you're right - he did say INT. Although, now I'm a little confused because you couldn't have an INT in the form of `000044`... the leading zeros would be removed...

Comment: @MarkM Now me too :) haha

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
$time = '001122';

$minutes = substr("$time", 0, 2); 
$seconds = substr("$time", 2, 2); 
$mills = substr("$time", 4, 2); 

echo $newTime = "$minutes:$seconds:$mills";
```